# Rails has_many :through association: save instance into join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, orm, relational-database

In our Rails app, there are 3 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end
```

And here are the corresponding migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateAdministrations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :administrations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :role

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

We have created the `calendar#create` action as follows:

```
def create
    @calendar = current_user.calendars.build(calendar_params)
    if @calendar.save
      flash[:success] = "Calendar created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

And the corresponding `_calendar_form.html.erb` partial:

```
<%= form_for(@calendar) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Your new calendar name" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This "works" since, when we create a new calendar through the form, it does show up in Rails console, when we type `Calendar.all`.

However, it seems like no new `@administration` is being created and the Administration table is not updated, as nothing returns when we type `Administration.all` in the console.

We thought the Administration table, which is the join table between the User table and the Calendar table, and which respectively contains `user_id` and `calendar_id` columns, would be updated automatically when creating a new calendar.

How can we achieve this? Do we need to create a specific `administration#create` action?

UPDATE: based on the comments and the answers, we implemented the following `CalendarsController`:

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @calendar = current_user.calendars.build(calendar_params)
    if @calendar.save
      current_user.administrations << @calendar
      @calendar.administration.role = 'creator'
      flash[:success] = "Calendar created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

...
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in CalendarsController#create

unless record.is_a?(reflection.klass) || record.is_a?(reflection.class_name.constantize)
            message = "#{reflection.class_name}(##{reflection.klass.object_id}) expected, got #{record.class}(##{record.class.object_id})"
            raise ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch, message
          end
        end

app/controllers/calendars_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

Are we missing something?

Comment: does `User.find(<currrent_users_id>).calendars` return anything?

Comment: Yes, it returns: SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')'
User.find(<currrent_users_id>).calendars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use current_user.calendars.build(calendar_params), you will only get new calendar, no administration.

If you use current_user.calendars.create(calendar_params), you will get both administration and calendar saved into database.

If you want to check whether calendar is successfully saved first, I use this approach:

```
def create
  @calendar = Calendar.build(calendar_params)
  if @calendar.save
    current_user.administrations << @calendar
    flash[:success] = "Calendar created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

UPDATED:

There is an error to associate calendar to user. This should be the correct one:

```
def create
  @calendar = current_user.calendars.build(calendar_params)
  if @calendar.save
    current_user.calendars << @calendar
    flash[:success] = "Calendar created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it fixes the problem indeed. We still have a small issue: we defined a `role` column in the `administration` table and we need to current_user to get the `creator` by default when the calendar (and the corresponding administration) is created. I tried `current_user.administration.role << "Creator"` but it does not seem to do the trick. Sorry if that is a dumb question.

Comment: This answer artifically binds two classes together in a controller action, which is typically considered an anti-pattern. To answer your last comment, @ThibaudClement, if you used the first example in my answer you'd be able to do something like: `@calendar.administration.role = 'creator'` since the `administration` object is created on initialization.

Comment: Thanks. We tried to implement what (we thought) you suggested but got some error. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: There are two errors I made. Please see the update for details. The first is **Calendar.build** should be **current_user.calendars.build** or **Calendar.new**. The second is **current_user.calendars << @calendar** instead of **current_user.administrations**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you absolutely do! You're not getting a new `Administration` object because you're not asking the system for one.

If you really, truly needed to create a new `Administration` object every time a `Calendar` was created, you could do something like this:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :administration

  def initialize(params)
    @administration = Administration.new(params[:id])
  end
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize(id_param_from_calendar)
    calendar_id = id_param_from_calendar
  end
end
```

Obviously this isn't a best practice, as it injects dependencies in your code. Now, no matter what, your `Calendar` class is aware that an `Administration` class not only exists, but uses its `id` column to initialize. This was just an example to answer your question.

Another example would be to include an `after_initialize` hook in your `Calendar` class like so (please note the `autosave: true` which is useful for ensuring the automatic saving of child objects):

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy

  after_initialize :init_admins

  def init_admins
    # you only wish to add admins on the newly instantiated Calendar instances
    if new_record?
      3.times { Administration.new self }
    end
  end

end
```

What's more, you could also include the above logic in an `after_create` hook. The only difference is that `after_create` occurs after an object's creation and `after_initialize` occurs after an object is either instantiated or loaded from the database.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I understand this part: "3.times { administrations.build }". Could you explain?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer to provide an explanation that may be a little easier to grasp. Now, we just build 3 new `Administration` objects, all of which are autosaved with that `autosave: true` statement on the association.