# Rails has_many :through association: Updating all 3 models at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, orm, relational-database

This question follows up on [Rails has_many :through association: save instance into join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173677/rails-has-many-through-association-save-instance-into-join-table) and I am restating things here for more clarity.

In our Rails app, there are 3 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end
```

And here are the corresponding migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :total_calendar_count
      t.integer :owned_calendar_count

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateAdministrations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :administrations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :role

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Here is what we are trying to accomplish:

*When a logged in user (`current_user`) creates a calendar, we should:*

- Create a new `@calendar` and save it to the Calendar table
- Assign the "Creator" role to the user (current_user) for this newly created calendar through the Role column in the Administration table
- Increment the `total_calendar_count` and the `owner_calendar_count` columns of the User table

In order to do that, we think we need to work on calendars#create.

In the CalendarsController, we already have the following code:

```
def create
    @calendar = current_user.calendars.create(calendar_params)
    if @calendar.save
      flash[:success] = "Calendar created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

And we collect data from users through the following `_calendar_form.html.erb` form:

```
<%= form_for(@calendar) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Your new calendar name" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

We are considering updating the controller as follows:

```
def create
    @calendar = current_user.calendars.create(calendar_params)
    @current_user.total_calendar_count += 1
    @current_user.owned_calendar_count += 1
    current_user.administrations << @calendar.id
    @calendar.administration.role = 'Creator'
    if @calendar.save
      flash[:success] = "Calendar created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in CalendarsController#create
Administration(#70307724710480) expected, got Fixnum(#70307679752800)

unless record.is_a?(reflection.klass) || record.is_a?(reflection.class_name.constantize)
    message = "#{reflection.class_name}(##{reflection.klass.object_id}) expected, got #{record.class}(##{record.class.object_id})"
    raise ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch, message
  end
end

app/controllers/calendars_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

How can we make it work?

Comment: `@calendar = current_user.calendars.create(calendar_params)` should be `@calendar = Calendar.create(calendar_params)` to create the new calendar.  You are getting an error b/c `current_user.calendars` does not return something which has a Calendar class create method.

Comment: @steveklein `current_user.calendars.create(calendar_params)` works just fine even if `current_user.calendars` returns no calendars back.

Comment: Learned something new... thanks @Arslan.

Comment: @steveklein Welcome. I learned too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is actually causing the error: `current_user.administrations << @calendar.id`.

`current.administrations` expects an object of type `Administration` while you are passing a `Fixnum` into it.

You can accomplish the same functionality in the following way:

```
current_user.administrations.create(calendar_id: @calendar.id)
```

**Edit:**

As OP asked in comments that it is a good practice or not. See, there is rule that says that *controllers should be skinny, and models should be fatty.* Well, it means you should try to write minimum code, and all the logic and fetching of objects should be there in models. But that isn't the case in your code scenario. You should move your code into model, and then call that into your controller.

Here's how:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def add_calendar_and_role(calendar_id, role)
    self.administrations.find_by(calendar_id: calendar_id).update(role: role)
  end
end
```

This way, your code reduces to just:

```
current_user.add_calendar_and_role(@calendar.id, 'Creator')
```

And on the same way, you can further refactor your controller code.

Comment: Thanks. This code partially works. Indeed, it does create a calendar. But it actually seems to create two. Our guess: a first one is created when we run `@calendar = current_user.calendars.create(calendar_params)` and a second one is created because of `current_user.administrations.create(calendar_id: @calendar.id)`. Is there a way to create a new @calendar and update the corresponding @administration (the one where calendar_id == @calendar.id) with the 'Creator' role?

Comment: We found a solution: we replaced `current_user.administrations.create(calendar_id: @calendar.id)` with `current_user.administrations.find_by(calendar_id: @calendar.id).update(role: 'Creator')`. It does work, but is it a good practice or another anti-pattern that is the fruit or our inexperience?

Comment: Your "edit" code worked like a charm. Thanks for reminding us of the "Fat model, skinny controller" rule, much appreciate it.